# Toggle classes with radio button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a set of radio buttons where when I click a radio button, I want the label to change color or whatever. But when I click another radio button, the color goes away. Therefore I have something like this:

```
jQuery('label').mouseup(function(){
   jQuery(this).prev().attr('checked', 'checked');
   jQuery('input').next().removeClass('selected');
   jQuery('input:checked').next().addClass('selected');

});
```

if you need to see some html:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="myRadio" value="option-1" />
<label for="radio1">Label 1</label>


<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="myRadio" value="option-2" />
<label for="radio2">Label 2</label>
```

This first removes 'selected' class from all the labels and then re-applies to only the checked labels.

It works and is simple, but I was thinking this might not be the most efficient way of doing this. I imagine that javascript is iterating through each input element and using more resources than necessary.

I'm curious if anyone knows of a common way of doing this more efficiently. I seem to be doing this type of thing quite often in my jQuery code. I've just been using jQuery for the past 3 months or so btw.

Comment: In my opinion, your code is Ok.
I would do in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things I think are worth mentioning.

Clicking on a `<label>` will automatically change the value of the `<input>`.  You don't need to set the `checked` attr manually, and therefore could bind to the `change` event on the radios instead.  This will also allow keyboard events to select/deselect the radios, and will work anytime the radio values change, not just when someone raises their mouse over a label.

Also, you can save the whole collection of radio inputs in its own variable to make referencing them later not have to search through the DOM again.

Suggested code (w/ [jsfiddle preview](http://www.jsfiddle.net/buATP/))

```
var $radios = jQuery('input[type=radio]');
$radios.change(function() {
   $radios.next().removeClass('selected');
   $radios.filter(':checked').next().addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Be aware that if you add any radio buttons dynamically, this won't pick them up because it stores the references after computing them the first time.  That's likely not an issue, but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Very true - if we wanted to handle dynamic radios, I would assume the OP would have been using `.live()` in the original.

Comment: I only put the checked attr in because otherwise it would add the class to the previously selected radio label.

I wasn't aware of the change event.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the use of `mouseup` who seems a little bit unusual in this case (at least, to me), your code is fine.

I'd use `click` or `change`.

Comment: Use change - that way people (like me) who tab through and select radios with spacebar presses will still get your events

Comment: Good thinking ;) I edited my answer since mouseup is not fine in this case.

Comment: Yea I usually use click, but I tried mouseup to try something else and left it there. I didn't see a difference between click and mouseup in this case. But I'll take a look at change.

Comment: `mouseup` vs `click`... the only difference is that `click` expects a `mousedown` event followed by a `mouseup` event. So, you can't `mousedown` anywhere on the page and then `mouseup` on the particular element and have the event fire. At least that's how I understand it to work, fundamentally.

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like it works when clicking the label.  I wouldn't worry too much about the number of DOM elements searched as long as the performance is ok.  Optimize when it becomes a problem and not before.  Clarity/readability is probably more important.  You might be able to improve it, though, by using some information from the label or its related input to narrow down the selectors.  Using `end` and `filter` would also allow you to reuse the second query.

```
$('label').click(function(){
   var radio = $(this).prev();
   radio.attr('checked', 'checked'); 
   var name = radio.attr('name');
   $('input[name=' + name ']').next()
                              .removeClass('selected')
                              .end()
                              .filter(':checked')
                              .next()
                              .addClass('selected'); 

});
```

Note that using `change` on the actual radios, as some others suggest might be better.  You could use the same techniques with that.

```
$('input[type=radio]').change( function() {
     $('input[type=radio]').next()
                           .removeClass('selected')
                           .end()
                           .filter(':checked')
                           .next()
                           .addClass('selected');
});
```

Use `live` handlers if you are adding radios dynamically to the page.